# Editing XML Nodes through SimpleXML PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I know similar questions have been asked several times, but I can't find a solution to the following:

I've got a simple XML file:
servers.xml

```
<servers>

    <server>
        <name> Google </name>
        <address>http://www.google.com</address>
    </server>

    <server> 
        <name> Yahoo </name>
        <address>http://www.yahoo.com</address>
    </server>

    <server>
        <name> Bing </name>
        <address>http://www.bing.com</address>
    </server>

</servers>
```

Now, I'm trying to get the `<server>` node which has a name of "Google" for example, and then change the address tag.
I have no idea how to go about it using SimpleXML.
So an example scenario would the following:

1. Get the server object/array where $serverName = "Google"
2. Edit the server's address field to something  different like http://www.google.co.uk
3. Write the changes back to the XML file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Three downvotes and no comments?  This is what I needed and has two good answers.  Go figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Get the server object/array where $serverName = "Google"

   ```
   // An array of all <server> elements with the chosen name
   $googles = $servers->xpath('server[name = " Google "]');
   ```
2. Edit the server's address field to something different like http://www.google.co.uk

   ```
   //Find a google and change its address
   $google->address = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
   ```
3. Write the changes back to the XML file.

   ```
   $servers->saveXML('path/to/file.xml');
   ```

**Full example**

```
$servers = simplexml_load_file('path/to/file.xml');
$googles = $servers->xpath('server[name=" Google "]');
foreach ($googles as $google) {
    $google->address = 'http://www.google.co.uk';
}
$servers->saveXML('path/to/file.xml');
```

**More info**

- [SimpleXML Basic Usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)
- [XPath tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html)

Answer (score 1):

Load the XML file using `simplexml_load_file`, loop through the `<server>` nodes, check if the   is Google, and if it is True, change the .

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("simple.xml");
foreach($xml->server as $server){
    ($server->name == trim("Google")) ? $server->address = "http://www.google.co.uk" : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you to modify the xml and get back in a text formate.

```
$xml_obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($xml_obj->server as $value) {
    /*Do something here*/
}
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
$doc->loadXML($xml_obj->asXML());
$output = $doc->saveXML();
```